# How to insert multiple image into one mysql database row?

Tags: php, mysql

Okay briefly I would like to say whats my problem with the code I have. The code below uploads image data into mysql database beautifully except with one barrier. On the form I have, people can upload up to 4 images. Now, the code below inserts four different rows. Each image 1 row. but the title for all four rows is the same because it belongs to same post. Is there anyway I can do a comma delimited insertion so that all four images for the single post be in one row?

[image]

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['submitting'])) 
      {
      if(isset($_FILES['file_array']))
         {
            $user = $_SESSION['user_id'];
            $pname = $_POST['Product_Name'];
            $ProPrice = $_POST['Product_fee'];
            $n_array = $_FILES['files_array']['name'];
        $tmp_name_array = $_FILES['files_array']['tmp_name'];
        $type_array = $_FILES['files_array']['type'];
        $size_array = $_FILES['files_array']['size'];
        $error_array = $_FILES['files_array']['error'];
        for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++)
        {
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], "data/profile/posted_data/".$n_array[$i]))
            {
                $query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO posts (userid, post_title, file, type, size, image_date) VALUES ('$user', '$pname', '$n_array[$i]', '$type_array[$i]', '$size_array[$i]', now())");
                echo '<div class="form_message_box">' . $n_array[$i] . '   ' . 'Uploaded Successfully' . '</div>' . '<br>';
                if($query) 
                                        {
                       echo '' . '<br>';
                    }
                        else
                    {
                       echo 'failed!' . '<br>';
                                        }
            }
        }
    }
 }
?>


            $posts = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE userid='$user'";
        $posts_result = mysqli_query($conn, $posts);
        $res = mysqli_num_rows($posts_result);
        while ($posts_result_rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($posts_result)) {
                                  $post_image = $posts_result_rows['files'];
                            }

                            <tr>
                <td width="220">
                <?php 
                                <img src="<?php echo "data/profile/posted_data/".$post_image; ?>" width="220" height="220"><hr>

                </td>        
            </tr>

    <?php
            }
    echo "</table>";                
    ?>
```

Comment: Why? It is better to insert them in separate rows for each image.

Comment: @Logan Wayne well, the reason is that for example when another user wants to see all of the posted images by a user, the post would be divided into 4 different posts even though the titles and and everything else is the same but pictures are different. I want it so that all four images belong to single post.

Comment: That is why you need to have a better schema. If that is my project, I would create a separate table for storing the `post_title` and would just index it to that table. And they way you store files right now is correct.

Comment: @koroush the problem is hat you had your insert inside you for loop. the answer is posted below. by Syed.

Comment: define relations. in your case one post can have many(4) images, so implement it that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need a different schema:

```
Table 1:
- userid
- id 
- post_title

Table 2:
- id
- post_id (FK for table 1)
- file
- type
- size
- image_date
- sort (if you want to sort the images)
```

With the relationship 1:many you can add as many images for one title as you want and at the same time not have any duplicate data.

**Pros of this answer:**

- Better database performance and better schema
- Easier SQL queries (*like `INNER JOIN`, `DISTINCT BY`, etc.*)

**Cons of what you want to achieve right now** (*if you continue the logic you have right now, where you want to store the file name into a single string for a single post*):

- Slower performance
- When you fetch a data for a single post (e.g. `Dadashi.jpg, 3.jpg, 2.jpg`), you have to use functions like `explode()` and then run them in a loop in order to display them in a `<img>`.
- When you want to add an image for a post, you have to fetch the `file` and then add the string of the new file name, then `UPDATE` it back to your table

An example for it:

Fetch all the post by (*I would use [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)*):

```
if($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT userid, id, post_title FROM table1")){ /* FETCH ALL POST QUERY */
  $stmt->execute(); /* EXECUTE QUERY */
  $stmt->store_result(); /* NECESSARY WHEN NESTING A SECOND STATEMENT */
  $stmt->bind_result($userid,$id,$post_title); /* BIND RESULT TO THESE QUERIES */
  while($stmt->fetch()){ /* START FETCHING ALL POST RESULTS */

    ?>
      <tr> <!-- START ROW -->
        <td><?php echo $post_title; ?></td> <!-- FIRST COLUMN IS THE TITLE -->
        <td> <!-- SECOND COLUMN IS THE FILES ATTACHED FOR THIS POST -->
    <?php

    if($stmt2 = $con->prepare("SELECT post_id, file, type, size, image_date, sort FROM table2 WHERE id = ?")){ /* PREPARE THE QUERY THAT WILL FETCH ALL FILES ATTACHED FOR THE CURRENT POST */
       $stmt2->bind_param("i",$id); /* BIND THIS VARIABLE TO THE QUERY; i STANDS FOR INTEGER */
       $stmt2->execute(); /* EXECUTE QUERY */
       $stmt2->store_result(); 
       $stmt2->bind_result($postid,$file,$type,$size,$imagedate,$sort); /* BIND THE RESULTS TO THESE VARIABLES */
       while($stmt2->fetch()){ /* START FETCHING ALL FILES FROM THE CURRENT FETCHED POST */
         ?>
           <img src="data/profile/posted_data/<?php echo $file; ?>" width="220" height="220"><br>
         <?php
       } /* END OF FETCHING FILES FOR THE CURRENT FETCHED POST */
       $stmt2->close();
    } /* END OF SECOND PREPARED STATEMENT */
    ?>
        </td> <-- END OF COLUMN -->
      </tr> <!-- END OF ROW -->
    <?php

  } /* END OF WHILE LOOP */
  $stmt->close();
} /* END OF PREPARED STATEMENT */
```

Comment: I already have different table actually the post table is the child table.

Comment: @koroush I suspect there should be an 'attachments' table (a 'child table' for each post).

Comment: I agree with @user2864740, there's no reason to stop you from having a child table for a child table

Comment: @koroush - you need to realize that you are on the right track, you just have to consider @NaguibIhab's solution. This will have a better performance than storing `Dadashi.jpg, 3.jpg, 2.jpg` in a single row (_where you will have to use `explode()` when fetching the images; and when you want to add more image, you have to fetch first image row and add the string of the new file, then update it back to that row; and many more_).

Comment: @Naguib Ihab I think I am going to give your solution a try. Please stay tuned for my update.

Comment: @NaguibIhab so the post_id would be the foreign key for which primary key? and also when letting users doing a post, in this case I have to write another insert query right? one for the post title and its information and another for the sub-child table which is for the images only. am I right?

Comment: The post_id would be a foreign key for the `id` column in the post table. And yes you have to write insert &select queries to accommodate this change

Comment: @NaguibIhab okay I did it all and now everything works fine but it won't display all of the images belonging to the single post. so I did set the post_id as FK of id but now it only shows one of the images. any suggestions?

Comment: @koroush You're probably missing a loop, can you post your code & queries in another question and post the link here?
And since it worked out with you can you mark my answer as correct so that anyone facing the same issue can do the same thing?

Comment: @NaguibIhab how would I assign a id to image though because right now my foreign key is messed up it auto increments and follows the user id but the problem is if I have two images, then one only shows up.

Comment: @NaguibIhab thank you all for helping me but I have one last question and that is how can I show all of the images. What loop should I use here? here is my query for selecting images from the database:        

 <?php 
      $image_posts = "SELECT image_id FROM image_data WHERE client_id='$user'";
   $image_result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $image_posts);
   $img_res = mysqli_num_rows($image_result);
    
  ?>

image_id is a column auto incremented in my child table
client_id is a FK that references to user_id in my parent table.

Comment: @koroush You don't need to have the client_id associated with the image, instead you need to associate the images in the post with the post itself. However as to why you're receiving only one entry I can't know with the information I have, can you post your tables schemas & the data in them in another question because you won't be able to format the tables here. Use that tool to draw the tables and put them in the question: http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
<?php
   $images = array();
   $type = array();
   $size = array();
   if(isset($_POST['submitting'])) 
      {
      if(isset($_FILES['file_array']))
         {
            $user = $_SESSION['user_id'];
            $pname = $_POST['Product_Name'];
            $ProPrice = $_POST['Product_fee'];
            $n_array = $_FILES['files_array']['name'];
        $tmp_name_array = $_FILES['files_array']['tmp_name'];
        $type_array = $_FILES['files_array']['type'];
        $size_array = $_FILES['files_array']['size'];
        $error_array = $_FILES['files_array']['error'];
        for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++)
        {
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], "data/profile/posted_data/".$n_array[$i]))
            {
                $images[] = $n_array[$i];
                $type[] = $type_array[$i];
                $size[] = $size_array[$i];
                echo '<div class="form_message_box">' . $n_array[$i] . '   ' . 'Uploaded Successfully' . '</div>' . '<br>';

            }
        }
  $all_images = implode(",",$images);
  $all_types = implode(",",$type);
  $all_sizes = implode(",",$size);
  $query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO posts (userid, post_title, file, type, size, image_date) VALUES ('$user', '$pname', 'all_images', '$type', '$size', now())");
                if($query) 
                                        {
                       echo '' . '<br>';
                    }
                        else
                    {
                       echo 'failed!' . '<br>';
                                        }
    }
 }

?>
```

Extra Edit code

```
    $posts = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE userid='$user'";
    $posts_result = mysqli_query($conn, $posts);
    $res = mysqli_num_rows($posts_result);
    while ($posts_result_rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($posts_result)) {
                              $post_image = $posts_result_rows['files'];
                        }

                        <tr>
            <td width="220">
            <?php 
                 $images = expolde(",",$post_image);
                 foreach($images as $image)
                 {
                 ?>
                            <img src="<?php echo 'data/profile/posted_data/'.$image; ?>" width="220" height="220"><hr>
                 <?php
                 }

            </td>        
        </tr>

<?php
        }
echo "</table>";                
?>
```

Comment: down voters any reason for down vote. this is the answer he requires.

Comment: mohammed thanks bro. it works to certain extend. the only problem I have now is that it won't insert the type and size information and I get a blank image.

Comment: mohammed thanks bro can you stay here for a minute I got another question and that is how would I show these on these images on the page? here is my current code for showing images: 

Please see edited post.